# Edittext set cursor to next line

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on custom keyboard where i have one problem. **On key
 listener** I need to set my current **cursor position to next line**. I have
 tried using

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

which sets the current cursor position to end of text not to next
 line.

Comment: to next line or next editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
editText.append("\n");
```

And than set the cursor to the end?

Comment: what is it? (you can also open a new question at the same price)

Comment: as i am working on keyboard, as we know on default keyboard on device when we click any key larger image is displayed, you which is this effect..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, and it doesn't seem related to this topic. Can you open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear to me, whether the insertion of a *new line* is desired as the *enter key* produces it in e.g. notepad.
In that case uval's answer seems fine, besides you might want to remember the current position of the cursor before inserting:

```
int position = editText.getSelectionStart();
editText.getText().insert(position, "\n");
editText.setSelection(position + 1);
```

Otherwise, if you just want to jump around in the text, as you can do with the *arrow keys* in notepad, you'll probably have to calculate the number of characters per line at the given width of your view and the size of its text and then get the number and position of the following line accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fnameUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_bar"
            android:hint="First Name"
            **android:text="@string/newline"**

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:padding="5dp" />
```

where

```
<string name="newline">\n</string>
```